# How do I select only first-level children of an element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, wildcard, children

How do I select all the first-level div elements marked below:

```html
<div>
  <a>         //
    <span></span>
  </a>
  <ul>         //
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
  <div>         //
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <span>         //
  </span>
</div>
```

When I use the wildcard selector it also selects the descendants. I only want the first-level children. How do I do it with css only?

Comment: Thats just an example. I want to select different elements with different classes/ids

Comment: Well, it is not clear. You need to post everything that you want to select. My deleted solution would also require some changes. If it has a class, then you can simply use `.className > div`

Comment: Edited to show multiple tags

Comment: What are you actually trying to select? Your updated code doesn't make it more clear. The reason: all of your children will inherit the parent styles unless otherwise specified.

Comment: Do you want to select the first level div elements (as in your text) or the first level elements (as marked in your code)? I don't think you can do either given the code you have posted - the top level div needs more defining else you run the risk of picking up divs further down the tree that also have children. If div is a direct child of body for example or some known container then it would be possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You could go with a *CSS* reset rule for this issue.**

First you set your style as you want it to look on your first level ***child*** elements, the you can use a *reset* rule *parentEl -> everything -> everything* --> `#el > * > *` to reset the style back to its default settings. Essentially this says *every child element* of *every child element* that is a child of the *parent* element.

***NOTE:*** Keep in mind that anything you style in the *initial* ***first-level*** of children will need to be reset to its default style within the `div > * > *` reset rule.

Though this is not needed, you could use the `:root` to set your default styles as **css variables**, so you have them all in one area, your root elements properties, and then call them on your *reset css properties*.

See the following snippit:

```css
:root {
  --def-color: black; 
}

div > * {
  color: red;
}
/* reset rule */
div > * > * {
  color: var(--def-color);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a>child level 1    //   
    <span>span child lvl 2</span>
    <div>div child lvl 2</div>
  </a>
  <ul>ul child level 1        //
    <li>li child level 2</li>
    <li>li child level 2</li>
    <li>
      <ul>ul child lvl 3
        <li>li child level 4</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div>child level 1         //
    <div>child level 2
      <div>child level 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <span>child level 1       //
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

with css select **div div:nth-child(1)**

example:

```
#big-div div:nth-child(1) {
  margin: 5px;
}

<div id="big-div">
        <div>         
          <div>1.text</div>
        </div>
        <div>         
          <div>2.text</div>
          <div>3.text</div>
        </div>
        <div>         
          <div>4.text</div>
        </div>
        <div>        
        </div>
    </div>
```